# socket.io only working on local machine, can't connect from another machine

Tags: html, mysql, sockets

```
var mysql = require('mysql')
// Let’s make node/socketio listen on port 3000
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000)
// Define our db creds
var db = mysql.createConnection({
host: 'localhost',
user: 'root',
database: 'node'
 })

 // Log any errors connected to the db
 db.connect(function(err){
 if (err) console.log(err)
 })

 // Define/initialize our global vars
 var notes = []
 var isInitNotes = false
 var socketCount = 0

 io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
  // Socket has connected, increase socket count
   socketCount++
  // Let all sockets know how many are connected
   io.sockets.emit('users connected', socketCount)

   socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    // Decrease the socket count on a disconnect, emit
    socketCount--
    io.sockets.emit('users connected', socketCount)
  })

   socket.on('new note', function(data){
    // New note added, push to all sockets and insert into db
    notes.push(data)
    io.sockets.emit('new note', data)
    // Use node's db injection format to filter incoming data
    db.query('INSERT INTO notes (note) VALUES (?)', data.note)
 })

  // Check to see if initial query/notes are set
   if (! isInitNotes) {
    // Initial app start, run db query
    db.query('SELECT * FROM notes')
        .on('result', function(data){
            // Push results onto the notes array
            notes.push(data)
        })
        .on('end', function(){
            // Only emit notes after query has been completed
            socket.emit('initial notes', notes)
        })

       isInitNotes = true
      } else {
    // Initial notes already exist, send out
       socket.emit('initial notes', notes)
     }
    })
```

My client script

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 // Connect to our node/websockets server
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

// Initial set of notes, loop through and add to list
socket.on('initial notes', function(data){
    var html = ''
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        // We store html as a var then add to DOM after for efficiency
        html += '<li>' + data[i].note + '</li>'
    }
    $('#notes').html(html)
})

// New note emitted, add it to our list of current notes
socket.on('new note', function(data){
    $('#notes').append('<li>' + data.note + '</li>')
})

// New socket connected, display new count on page
socket.on('users connected', function(data){
    $('#usersConnected').html('Users connected: ' + data)
})

// Add a new (random) note, emit to server to let others know
$('.gsub').click(function(){
    var value=$("#txt").val();
  //  var newNote = 'This is a random ' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1)  + ' note'
    socket.emit('new note', {note: value})
  })
  })
  </script>
  <ul id="notes"></ul>
  <div id="usersConnected"></div>
  <div id="newNote">Create a new note</div>
  <input type='text' name='txt' id='txt'><input type='button' value='submit' class='gsub'>
```

above both codes are working fine with local machine only `http://localhost/`,but not working when i'm trying to connect tha same form another machine which are locally connected together by my local ip `http://192.168.21.21/`, so please share your ideas to achive this, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it is because you have localhost hard coded in several places on your client side code. Try changing it to use something like window.location.host instead. For example, you current have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Connect to our node/websockets server
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
...
});
```

which should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Connect to our node/websockets server
    var host = window.location.host; // Get the host name here
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + url + ':3000'); //insert the http:// and :3000 here
...
});
```

That way when you access your server from another machine it will connect to http://192.168.21.21:3000 rather than it's own "localhost".

Also at the top of your HTML when your are pulling in the socket.io.js file make sure not to pull it from "localhost" again. Just put something like:

```
<script src="/scripts/socketio.js"></script>
```